# Make an array of the current batch of data with VueJS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create an `array` with the current `data` for every time the `toggle-function` is called. So when I call the `toggle-function` on the `group` with `pattern: "group1"` I want to be able to call `{{model.groups[0].pattern}}` and show `group2` on screen.

**Here you see the build-up of my data:**

```
{
  payload: 
    {
      groups: [{
        pattern: "group1",
        groups: [{
          pattern: "group2"
        }],
        routes: [{
          pattern: "route1"
        }]
      }],
      routes: [{
        pattern: "route2"
      }]
    }
}
```

**This is the toggle-function:**

```
toggle: function () {
  if (this.isGroup || this.isRoute) {
    this.open = !this.open
  }
}
```

**And this is how I call the toggle-function**

```
<div :class="{bold: isGroup || isRoute}">
  <div @click="toggle">
    <span v-if="model.pattern">{{model.pattern}}</span>
    <span v-if="isGroup || isRoute">[{{open ? '-' : '+'}}]</span>
  </div>
</div>
<ul v-show="open" v-if="isGroup || isRoute">
  <item
    class="item group"
    v-for="model in model.groups"
    :model="model">
  </item>
  <item
    class="item route"
    v-for="model in model.routes"
    :model="model">
  </item>
</ul>
```

Or maybe anyone has a way to seperate the list items from the tree view:

https://jsfiddle.net/inbar11/3p0j5sgy/33/

So that I can put the 1st layer children array in the second column (see it as `bootstrap-class col-md-3`) and the 2nd layer children in the third column.